# How can I make this docker image smaller?

Tags: php, apache, docker, dockerfile

I have the following dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
LABEL name "medico-app"
COPY composer.json composer.lock ./
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends git zip && composer install
COPY . /var/www/html
EXPOSE 80
```

When this image is built, it has a size of ~500 Mbs. I'm trying to compress this image to < 100 Mb so that I can use it on Zeit [Now](https://zeit.co/now). According to what I'm reading in the docker documentation, multi-stage builds sometimes help in making images smaller. My current idea is to split the dockerfile into two stages, one where I would install the dependencies with `compose` and the other where I'd just have `php` and `apache`. I can't seem to get it right though. Any suggestions?

This is what I have so far:

```
# first stage
FROM composer:latest
COPY composer.json composer.lock ./
RUN composer install
```

For the second stage, I tried this

```
FROM httpd:2.4-alpine
LABEL name "medico-app"
COPY --from=0 /app/vendor ./vendor
COPY . /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
EXPOSE 80
```

However when I run the container now, the php files aren't served, I just see them as text. Im probably missing something here with PHP/Apache.

**EDIT:**

I also tried this for the second stage but I can't get it to work:

```
FROM php:7.2-alpine
LABEL name "medico-app"
RUN apk --no-cache update && apk --no-cache add apache2 openrc
COPY --from=0 /app/vendor ./vendor
COPY . /var/www/
EXPOSE 80
```

Now when I open my localhost I don't see the PHP files that I should see. I just see the default `it works` page.

Comment: You could purge apt lists after installing your dependencies to save some space: `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`. But your problem will be more likely huge `vendor` folder.

Comment: @martinadamek The vendor folder is actually less than 5 MBs. The problem is the base image itself is > 300 MB.

Comment: Then maybe try installing alpine version of php and install apache manually.

Comment: @martinadamek That's what I'm trying to do (my last edit).

Answer (score 0):

General tips for making docker images smaller:

1. Use a minimal base image such as the alpine versions. In this case you can use something like `php:7.2-alpine` and install apache using apk.
2. When using apt-get follow the [best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#run). In particular add `&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`
3. Try minifiying the code being added to the image using something like [gulp minify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify).

Comment: I'm trying to do your first suggestions. I installed apache in the php:7.2 image however I can't figure out how to run it correctly and where to put my files.